# PHPExcel Phonenumber with /

Tags: phpexcel

Iam using the PHPExcel Version 1.8.0
There are phonenumbers like this: +44 20 / 5625650
then the script does not generate the Excel file because of the slash.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A:AE')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

I have Linux as operating system. In windows I did not get this problem.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set a cell value that could be interpreted as a numeric, but want to retain its formatting as a string, then you should explicitly store the value as a string when you set the cell value by using `setCellValueExplicit()` as described in the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#setting-a-number-with-leading-zeroes)

Comment: I do not know which column the phonenumber contains. Its dynamically. First I generate a big CSV file and than I convert it into a Excel file with PHPExcel.